# Jersey 2.3 not invoking HK2 service locator shutdown when servlet container is shut down

Tags: jersey, shutdown, hk2

Question: Is there a proper way to ensure that HK2 shuts down with Jersey 2; if not, would this be considered a bug?

Using jersey-server 2.3.1, I've noticed that HK2 `@PreDestroy` methods on managed singletons and `dispose()` methods on `Factory<T>` implementations are not being invoked.  Doing a bit of poking around, I see that `ConfigHelper` defines a lifecycle listener that invokes `preDestroy()` on the service locator, but nothing more.  This gets invoked from the the Jersey `ServletContainer` on both `shutdown()` and `reload()`, but nothing further is done with the service locator in terms of shutdown.

I've looked through `ServletContainer`, but there doesn't seem to be a way of accessing the HK2 service locator through any public or protected APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me solution is to invoke serviceLocator.shutdown() (I don't know why this method is not called automatically when service is shutdown). After call this method all dispose() methods will be called. Question where is a good place to invoke serviceLocator.shutdown()? Whell I have implementetion of ApplicationEventListener so service can listen for an event DESTROY_FINISHED, RELOAD_FINISHED. When service catch this event then serviceLocator.shutdown() is called. If you figure out better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up injecting ServiceLocator into my Application instance (assuming this is topmost ServiceLocator for my app) and calling `locator.shutdown()` in `MyApplication.preDestroy()` (its marked with @PreDestroy and called from jersey's ContainerLifecycleListener). Worked ok for me. Not sure however, that this is recommended way of doing it.

Comment: What is the Application instance? is it the class that extends ResourceConfig?

Comment: Yep, and it does something like `packages("org.my.ws.package")` and `register(new MyBinder())` in ctor.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved in jersey 2.7 (https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2299) and jersey 2.11 (https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2549). Updating your jersey dependency should fix things for you.